# Excel VBA Message Box when there are no blank fields in an autofilter and stop macro

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a simple macro to set one AutoFilter column(field 4) to a particular value, and a second AutoFilter column(field 5) to show only blank entries. Sometimes there are no blank entries and in this situation is there a way to stop the filter function and provide a message box to notify no blank entries were found?

When my code ends currently, the column(field 5) where there are no blanks to filter actually looks like an autofilter has been applied looking at the change of dropdown arrow state. The full non-blank cells are visible still.

```
Sub PoPODRecvdStatus()
'
' PoPODRecvdStatus Macro
' Filters Courier/Status by POD Received and Consignment to Blank
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$12543").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    "POD RECEIVED"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$12543").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So you are saying after the macro has ruin you still have rows where column 5 is blank, right? Maybe you have White Spaces there, but you should see additonal entries in the drop down for these eintries in the auto filter

Comment: The macro runs and looks like it has filtered out blanks when there is none there to begin with. So the little drop down arrow on the column header changes from a down arrow to the filtered symbol.

Comment: Yes, but the question is: Do you still have blank entries in column 5?

Comment: No, the column (field 5) has no blanks, just data

Comment: Then I do not understand what your problem is. You need to clarify, at least for me. Please edit your post in order to makt it clearer, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. Ok, so i have two columns of data,when the first column is filtered on "POD RECEVIED" the user then wants to see if the second column has any blank fields so they know there is some data missing that needs to be input. There can be the scenario where everything is up to date and all the cells in the filtered "POD RECEIVED" column has data in the corresponding column, therefore, no work to do. What i am looking to do is return a message that says there are no blank cells, and have the macro stop the filter process on blanks. does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment I understand you might want to have something like that. The code will display a message box if there is no blank cell when filtered on POD RECEIVED and display these lines otherwise it will display the "blanks" with POD RECEIVED

```
Sub PoPODRecvdStatus()
'
' PoPODRecvdStatus Macro
' Filters Courier/Status by POD Received and Consignment to Blank
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$12543").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
                                                  "POD RECEIVED"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$12543").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    If rng.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No blank cells in column 5 for POD RECEIVED", vbOKOnly, "POD_RECEIVED"
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$12543").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Storax, this is great and makes sense, So i ran the code and nothing happened  until i realised that i'd made an error in the initial criteria for setting column(5). I'd set it to filter on non-blanks which you spotted for me, so thanks for that. I've also amended the last part of the code to reset all the filters for the user , so they can move forward. Just replaced the last line before the End If to "  ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData". Thank you for your time on this, much appreciated.